# How to use volatile with 2D shared memory?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I was wondering **how** to declare a volatile pointer to two dimensional shared memory and if this would have **the same effect** as for one dimensional arrays.

```
__shared__ float 2d_array[32][32];
// not working: volatile T ** smem = sdata;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your "two dimensional" shared memory array is, in fact, only one dimensional. So something like this:

```
__shared__ volatile float array_2d[32][32]; 
volatile float *smem = &array_2d[0][0]; 
float val = *(smem + y + 32*x) // address of s2_array[x][y]
```

is what you want. The static array `array_2d` is stored in row major order and can be accessed as I have shown.